# 404 error when accessing website with parameters (vuejs)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, http-status-code-404, web-hosting

I am working on a website using VueJS and just figured out how to do url parameters, which works well on my local machine. I can navigate to a page, and copy the full link including parameters in my browser and the page loads the same way.

Example: I type `localhost:8080` to load the index site, navigate to `localhost:8080/param1/param2` to go to another site, everything works fine. I can even type in `localhost:8080/param1/param2` DIRECTLY (without going to index page first) and it works too.

However, after a build and upload to my web hosting provider, I can not type in the url with parameters DIRECTLY, it only works when navigating from index page.

I can the following error:

[404 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egqbm.png)

I have almost no experience with routing and web hosting and even after extensive research could not find a solution online. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Additional information based on comments I've received:

Web host:
I have a login to Plesk where I can manage my settings. There I have "Apache & nginx" settings which look like this:

[Apache Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMmO5.png)

[nginx Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLYpd.png)

Comment: Maibe there is NGINX who redirect all routes to 404 if is not index

Comment: Could you please add more information about what hosting service you are using, aas well as what you mean by "works when navigating from index page" ?

Comment: @Radeanu I edited my post to include web host settings, does this answer your question? Sorry I'm very inexperienced with web hosting

Comment: @FilipRazek To me it looks like it's powered by Apache & nginx. What I mean by that: I have a link on my index page navigating to index/component/url/param etc. Clicking on it, it works fine. But simply posting this whole URL to browser search bar, it returns 404. Sorry if this is still confusing I can upload pictures or a video.

Comment: Try to delete **mode: history** from **VueRouter**

Comment: @Radeanu That was it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that SPA's do not have different HTML pages for different URL's like conventional pages. So, you have to either redirect all the requests to the `index.html` page in the server settings or set the history property to this `history: createWebHashHistory()`.

Let me know if this works.

P.S: Sorry I don't know how to configure the settings for this in Apache or Nginx

Comment: That's exactly the problem. After even more research, your help and help from others in the comments I came across this: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations which 1:1 describes what I'm experiencing. I marked your answer as the solution.